# How to list all deployments using given ConfigMap in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm, configmap

Is there an easy way to query for all deployments that use given ConfigMap as valueFrom: configMapKeyRef.

I need to know which deployments use my config map in order to be able to restart them after the config map changes.

I'm looking for something like:

`kubectl get deployments --with-config-map my-config-map`

Comment: What does "using a ConfigMap" even mean? Do you mean "mounts it as a volume"? Or "uses it in an `envFrom` block"? Etc?

Comment: @larsks I mean valueFrom: configMapKeyRef

Comment: i just got it running with  jq: `kubectl get deploy -o json | jq '. | select(.items[].spec.template.spec.volumes[]?.configMap?.name == "name-of-configmap")'`

Comment: I used the answer from https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/get-all-deployments-referencing-given-configmap-by-the-configmaps-name (adapt if you want to use volumes)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it as easily as you want. However you can still get the data you want in one command by using [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) as the output of your kubectl command.

Answer (score 0):

thank to @OreOp. As quick answer I paste here some example I tried, it list all pods and their configMap name

```
kubectl get pods \
-o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}{"::"}{.metadata.name}{"\t\t"}{.spec.volumes[*]..configMap.name}{"\n"}{end}' -A
```

range can be nested:

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}{"::"}{.metadata.name}{"\t\t"}{range .spec.volumes[*]..configMap}{.name}{", "}{end}{"\n"}{end}' -A
```

but output is not so nice:

```
kube-system::calico-kube-controllers-74d5f9d7bb-wpk4t       kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::calico-node-62cpd      kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::calico-node-bxpbm      kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::calico-node-xc4w5      kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::coredns-5dd5756b68-h8xlz       coredns, kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::coredns-5dd5756b68-k2zf5       coredns, kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::etcd-unode1        
kube-system::kube-apiserver-unode1      
kube-system::kube-controller-manager-unode1     
kube-system::kube-proxy-gzt65       kube-proxy, kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::kube-proxy-tmvp9       kube-proxy, kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::kube-proxy-x7djq       kube-proxy, kube-root-ca.crt, 
kube-system::kube-scheduler-unode1
```